# Accessing TaublarData from javascript

Tags: javascript, jmx

I am trying to invoke jmx from javascript code using node-jmx module https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmx.

The code is able to return Composite data and it can be accessed using the getSync('nameofitem') function, but i am confused on how to access it in case of Tabular data.  Since tabular data is like an array of CompositeData we would have to treat it as an array.

Would be very helpful is someone know how this can be done.

Regards
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue 
  client.getAttribute("com.test.mgmt.mbeans:type=TestGroupMBean", "TestGroups",
      function(data) {
          console.log(data.entrySetSync() + " ");
          var iterator = data.entrySetSync().iteratorSync();
          while (iterator.hasNextSync()){
          console.log("Value: "+iterator.nextSync().getValueSync().getSync('name')+ " ");
   }